# REST for Microsoft Access (or another way to access from App)

Tags: database, rest, ms-access

I have an Access database on a PC and want to write a small App, that can CRUD the data in this database. I would write a simple C# service that provides this functionality, but I don't want to rewrite something existing.

Is there a Windows Service or Tool, that provides a REST Interface to a Microsoft Access database?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MSN-REST-WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412178%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This is at a basic level. But should give you something to start with.

Comment: As noted, the context of the question in regards to Access has nothing to do with Access and this answer does not mention Access in any way at all. So there nothing in this answer that address Access + REST at all in anyway whatsoever. As long as everyone keeps in mind that REST is a separate issue from the database system one happens to choose, then we are all ok here.

Comment: Your right on point Albert D Kallal. He was just wanted to know about an interface or service to access his Access DB.

Comment: I'm searching for an existing tool/service, that allows me to read/write my local MS Access Database Entities via REST or something similar. So it seems, that I have to implement it by myself. @AlbertD.Kallal I know that REST has nothing to do with a particular underlying database in general. But in my case it does

Answer (score -1):

Using the concepts of REST has ZERO to do with an Oracle database.

Using the concepts of REST has ZERO to do with a MySQL database.

Using the concepts of REST has ZERO to do with an SQL server database.

Using the concepts of REST has ZERO to do with an Access database.

So building a web site using REST is 100% neutral and has ZERO to do with the particular database system.

How you build a web site using REST with MySQL server or an Access database does NOT change.

So virtually any article on the web that shows one how to build a web site based on REST will apply to ANY database, and asking such a context in regards to Oracle, or Access makes ZERO sense.

How a REST site works with Oracle, or how a REST site will work with Access will not change.

Now of course we only talking about the data. The forms UI etc. used in Access application cannot be used for web based systems and there no real context of talking about VB6 forms, c# (desktop winforms), or Access desktop forms have ZERO relationship and ZERO context in regards to building web sites based on REST.

Comment: Wow... can I suggest you read the question before launching into your next rant.  The poster wants a tool to expose an existing MSAccess database through a rest API (tools exist to do this with other databases).

Comment: Does the poster want the api exposed as a socket interface, or a .dll library? Or how about a COM object? In fact are we even talking about a socket interface here at all? There is no socket interface for the access database. So does the poster need a socket based interface? The tags and topic are limited to Access – so the answer still stands. It also not clear if this is to be run via a web service either. In all cases limiting the tags to access and REST does not cut it. Would a win32 or win64 dll interface suffice here? (We don’t know) Ask a limited question then you get my kind of answer.

Comment: A rest api is a very specific thing.  It is an http server that returns data in json format from an underlying database.  The poster is asking if such a tool exists for access.